# tensorflowjs-node-gpu: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backend')

Tags: typescript, tensorflow.js

while experimenting with tensorflowjs the error as specified in the title occurs during training.

About the evironment:
ubuntu 22.04

Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119

tensorflowjs-node-gpu version 4.10.0
(and no other tensorflowjs packages installed)

node v19.9.0

I have found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4237) Issue on github and expect it to be something similar, but cant quite figure out how, since the provided link to the test case doesn't seem to work.

Anyway. Since the issue was resolved by a mistake in the dataset, here my current dataset function.

```
import {
  Tensor1D,
  Tensor3D,
  Tensor4D,
  node,
  tensor1d,
  data,
} from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu";


export type Example = {
  xs: Tensor3D | Tensor4D; //input type generated from image
  ys: Tensor1D; //Output type
};

export const createDatast = async (
  projectId: string,
  imageList: Record<string, number[]> //name of the image and the expected output
): Promise<data.Dataset<Example>> => {
  return data.generator<Example>(() => iterator(projectId, shots));
};

export const iterator = async (
  projectId: string,
  imageList: Record<string, number[]>
): Promise<Iterator<Example, any, undefined>> => {
  const numElements = Object.keys(imageList).length - 1;
  let index = 0;
  return await getIteratorFn(imageList, projectId, index, !(index++ < numElements));
};

const getIteratorFn = async (
  imageList: Record<string, number[]>,
  projectId: string,
  index: number,
  done: boolean
) => {
  const value = await getExample(imageList, projectId, index);
  return { next: () => ({ value, done }) };
};

const getExample = async (
  imageList: Record<string, number[]>,
  projectId: string,
  index: number
): Promise<Example> => {
  const imageID = Object.keys(shots)[index];
  const image = await getDecodedImage(imageID, projectId); //function that fechtes an image an converets it to a tensor using tf.node.decodeImage
  const output = tensor1d(imageList[imageID]);
  const value = { xs: image, ys: output };

  return value;
};
```

Following the documentation [here](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.generator). As you can see i have tried to abstract it to be async and load each image as it is needed.

There is no error or warning during compilation when using it:

```
  const dataset = (await createDatast(projectId, imageList)).batch(1);
  await model.fitDataset(dataset, { 
    ...options
  });
```

I tried to understand what causes this error, but couldn't wrap my head around [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4237#issuecomment-729267099) , which seemed to have solved the github issue. According to the documentation I thought [fitDataset](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.LayersModel.fitDataset) needs:

> a Dataset object with elements of the form {xs: xVal, ys: yVal}, where xs and ys are the feature and label tensors, respectively.

, but [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4237#issuecomment-729267099) xs and ys seem to be of the same type.